# How can I use T-SQL instead of using execute method with appended text based on arrays?

Tags: postgresql

I have a function that returns products based on search criteria with the rating algorithm,

I need to provide the search query and array of ratings from 1-5 and return the listings/products.

```
I have a listings table as 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.listings
(
    listingid integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    generalrating numeric,
    CONSTRAINT clistings_pkey PRIMARY KEY (listingid)
)

I have a function to get the greatest in array


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.array_greatest(
    anyarray)
    RETURNS anyelement
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
  SELECT max(elements) FROM unnest($1) elements
$BODY$;

This is the main function called to get listings based on search criteria

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.searchlistings(
    searchquery character varying,
    stars integer[]
    )
    RETURNS TABLE(productname character varying) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    appendtext text := 'Select cr.listingname as productname
        FROM listings cr 
        WHERE cr.listingname like  ''%' || $1 || '%'' ';
BEGIN
     
    
    IF cardinality(stars) = 0   
    THEN 
    
    ELSE
        appendtext := appendtext || ' and (';
        IF 5 = ANY($2)
        THEN appendtext := appendtext || '(cr.generalrating >= 4.25)';
        END IF;

        IF 4 = ANY($2)
        THEN
                IF array_greatest($2)::integer = 4
                THEN
                appendtext := appendtext || '(cr.generalrating >= 3.25 and cr.generalrating <= 4.24)';
                ELSE
                appendtext := appendtext || ' or (cr.generalrating >= 3.25 and cr.generalrating <= 4.24)';
                END IF;
        END IF;

        IF 3 = ANY($2)
        THEN
                IF array_greatest($2)::integer = 3
                THEN
                appendtext := appendtext || '(cr.generalrating >= 2.5 and cr.generalrating <= 3.24)';
                ELSE
                appendtext := appendtext || ' or (cr.generalrating >= 2.5 and cr.generalrating <= 3.24)';
                END IF;     
        END IF;

        IF 2 = ANY($2)
        THEN
                IF array_greatest($2)::integer = 2
                THEN
                appendtext := appendtext || '(cr.generalrating >= 1.75 and cr.generalrating <= 2.49)';
                ELSE
                appendtext := appendtext || ' or (cr.generalrating >= 1.75 and cr.generalrating <= 2.49)';
                END IF; 
        END IF;

        IF 1 = ANY($2)
        THEN
                IF array_greatest($2)::integer = 1
                THEN
                appendtext := appendtext || '(cr.generalrating >= 1 and cr.generalrating <= 1.74)';
                ELSE
                appendtext := appendtext || ' or (cr.generalrating >= 1 and cr.generalrating <= 1.74)';
                END IF;
        END IF;
        appendtext := appendtext || ')';
    
    END IF;
    
    
    
    appendtext := appendtext || ' order by cr.listingid desc';
    
    

   RETURN QUERY execute appendtext; 
END; 
$BODY$;
```

Do you this would be injection safe as I use execute  method? Are there any ways to make this query T-SQL without using execute method?

I have used case when with T-SQL but I was not successfull.

Comment: Postgres does not use/have `T-Sql`, that is a SQL Server/Sybase language. Therefore you cannot make this query `T-Sql`.

Comment: You can greatly simplify this function: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uiNnf8DC).